# Create table multi column multi row

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

I want to make a tabe like the picture. Could you help?

[image: table]

thanks for answers.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) As always on this website, please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/184389) of what you have tried so far showing what point exactly you are struggling with since "do it for me" questions are not well received. Indeed a lot of example on how to do such a table exist across the internet and even on this website.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                              % <== cells coloring

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}               % <=== sets serif font
\newcommand{\cc}{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.847, 0.894, 0.737}}  % <=== cells cloloring shortcut

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering                                          % <=== center the table
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}                   % <=== increase cells padding
    \begin{tabular}{|c|ccc|}
        \hline
        \shortstack{\\[1ex] y = numbers of\\ times city\\ name is stated\\[-2em]} &
        \multicolumn{3}{m{7em}|}{\centering x = number of bars of signal strength}\\ \cline{2-4}
          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3}\\ \hline
        1 & \cc 0.01 & \cc 0.02 & \cc 0.25 \\ \cline{1-1}
        2 & \cc 0.02 & \cc 0.03 & \cc 0.20 \\ \cline{1-1}
        3 & \cc 0.02 & \cc 0.10 & \cc 0.05 \\ \cline{1-1}
        4 & \cc 0.15 & \cc 0.10 & \cc 0.05\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]